# Re-install debian6 while running it

Tags: debian

Is it possible to re-install debian6 from debian6? Or is it only possible to do that from an external media (USB, cdrom etc.)?

Alternatively is it possible to restore a previous state of the OS?

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap

Comment: You can reinstall most of Debian from inside it using "apt-get --reinstall" but obviously this isn't the solution to your problem, which is a mixup of incompatible packages. I'll give another reply on the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall Debian from inside it: No. The installer requires a specific environment and needs to run from outside the disk you install the OS to. After all, an important step of the installation is to create new filesystems, deleting everything that's on them.

Restore previous state: That's what a backup is for. In general, the OS doesn't offer anything like that but depending on what you want to restore and how you run the system, some options might be available, like snapshots if you run it in a VM or with LVM.

What is your **real** problem?